# Everything matches but I still get "Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform"

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

So i'm pretty lost trying to get my app to fetch not only the desired text from firestore but also the image i placed there. I know the error "Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform" implies that either I'm missing field or there's something wrong with at least one of those fields. There's only four things I'm trying to fetch from firestore **"imgUrl, title, desc, organizer"** i have checked for spelling and order and i can't figure it out. I have also checked firestore to see if the order and spelling was correct and i dont see what's the issue. Please help, Thank you so much in advanced.

////////////////////////////// News Class Starts\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
import 'package:myfuji/screens/CrudMethods.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'CrudMethods.dart';
import 'add_blog.dart';

class News extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewsState createState() => _NewsState();
}

class _NewsState extends State<News> {
  CrudMethods crudMethods = CrudMethods();

  late QuerySnapshot blogSnapshot;

  @override
  void initState() {
    crudMethods.getData().then((result) {
      blogSnapshot = result;
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget blogsList() {
    return ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 24),
      itemCount: blogSnapshot.docs.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return BlogTile(
          organizer: blogSnapshot.docs[index].get('Organizer'),
          desc: blogSnapshot.docs[index].get('desc'),
          imgUrl: blogSnapshot.docs[index].get('imgUrl'),
          title: blogSnapshot.docs[index].get('title'),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Events"),
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: blogSnapshot != null
              ? blogsList()
              : const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddBlog()));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BlogTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imgUrl, title, desc, organizer;
  const BlogTile(
      {required this.organizer,
      required this.desc,
      required this.imgUrl,
      required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 24, right: 16, left: 16),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
              child: Image.network(
                imgUrl,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                height: 200,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 16),
          Text(
            title,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 2),
          Text(
            '$desc - By $organizer',
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////// class AddBlog begins here \\\\\\\\\\\

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:myfuji/screens/CrudMethods.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:random_string/random_string.dart';

class AddBlog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddBlogState createState() => _AddBlogState();
}

class _AddBlogState extends State<AddBlog> {
  //
  late File selectedImage;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  bool isLoading = false;

  CrudMethods crudMethods = new CrudMethods();

  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        selectedImage = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> uploadBlog() async {
    if (selectedImage != null) {
      // upload the image

      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });
      Reference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child("events/")
          .child("${randomAlphaNumeric(9)}.jpg");

      final UploadTask task = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(selectedImage);

      var imageUrl;
      await task.whenComplete(() async {
        try {
          imageUrl = await firebaseStorageRef.getDownloadURL();
        } catch (onError) {
          print("Error");
        }

        print(imageUrl);
      });

      // print(downloadUrl);

      Map<String, dynamic> blogData = {
        "imgUrl": imageUrl,
        "Organizer": authorTextEditingController.text,
        "title": titleTextEditingController.text,
        "desc": descTextEditingController.text
      };

      crudMethods.addData(blogData).then((value) {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
        Navigator.pop(context);
      });

      // upload the blog info
    }
  }

  //
  TextEditingController titleTextEditingController =
      new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController descTextEditingController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController authorTextEditingController =
      new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Create Blog"),
        actions: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              uploadBlog();
            },
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                child: Icon(Icons.file_upload)),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: isLoading
          ? Container(
              child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ))
          : SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          getImage();
                        },
                        child: selectedImage != null
                            ? Container(
                                height: 150,
                                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24),
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                                  child: Image.file(
                                    selectedImage,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            : Container(
                                height: 150,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
                                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24),
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.camera_alt,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                      ),
                      TextField(
                        controller: titleTextEditingController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "enter title"),
                      ),
                      TextField(
                        controller: descTextEditingController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "enter desc"),
                      ),
                      TextField(
                        controller: authorTextEditingController,
                        decoration:
                            InputDecoration(hintText: "enter author name"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////// class CrudMethods begins here \\\\\\\\\\\

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class CrudMethods {
  Future<void> addData(blogData) async {
    print(blogData);
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("events/")
        .add(blogData)
        .then((value) => print(value))
        .catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }

  getData() async {
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("events/").get();
  }
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////firestore\\\\\\\\\\\\\

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This maybe related to having “/“ after collection name here:

```
.collection("events/")
```

Instead try this:

```
.collection("events")
```

Also it may be best to change child to collection here:

```
 Reference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref()
      .child("events/")
```

Try to see if you get data back by running this:

```
itemCount: blogSnapshot.docs.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {

 QuerySnapshot snap = blogSnapshot.data; // Snapshot
              List<DocumentSnapshot> items = snap.documents; // List of Documents
            DocumentSnapshot item = items[index]; Specific Document
        return BlogTile(
          organizer: item.data['Organizer'],
          desc: item.data['desc'],
          imgUrl: item.data['imgUrl'],
          title: item.data['title'],
        );
      },
```

I think you need to utilize a QueryDocumentSnapshot to access the data in the document.

Comment: I changed it and I still get the error                                                                                       
 ---"Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform---

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findKeyValueInMap (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:87:7)
#1      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findComponent (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:105:23)"

Comment: So as far as i can tell it has to do with the snapshot... i just can't figure out where.  -----return BlogTile(
          organizer: blogSnapshot!.docs[index].get('Organizer'),
          desc: blogSnapshot!.docs[index].get('desc'),
          imgUrl: blogSnapshot!.docs[index].get('imgUrl'),
          title: blogSnapshot!.docs[index].get('title'),
        );------------maybe here